# How to find the number of weeks in the following problem?

Tags: arithmetic

**Problem:** In a camp there were stored food of 48 soldiers for 7 weeks. if 8 more soldiers join the camp lets find for how many weeks it will be sufficient with the same food?​

*My approach:*
48 soldiers: 7 weeks

1 soldier: $ {7\times 48}$  weeks

($48+8$) soldiers:  $\dfrac{7\times 48}{56}=6$ weeks.

Is my approach correct?

Comment: This is correct indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your approach is good. Alternatively, using algebra instead of ratios:

The number of soldiers $s$ is [inversely proportional](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1390366/21813) to the number of weeks $w$ that the given food lasts. I.e., there is some constant $K$ such that $$sw=K.$$ So, $$s_1w_1=K=s_2w_2.$$

Since $s_1=48,\quad w_1=7,\quad s_2=48+8=56,$ $$w_2=6.$$

P.S. Such problems sometimes involve three related quantities (e.g., number of soldiers, number of weeks, number of combat rations) that are in direct and inverse proportion; in this case, a three-column table is a good way to keep track of the quantities as they vary with one another.