# Symbolic equation wording help

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How many days will *a* men take to mow *b* acres if *c* boys can mow *a* acres in *b* days, and each man's work equals that of *n* boys?

Correct textbook solution:

1. *c* boys can mow *a* acres in *b* days
2. 1 boy can mow *a* acres in *bc* days
3. *n* boys, or 1 man, can mow *a* acres in $\frac{bc}{n}$ days
4. *a* men can mow *a* acres in $\frac{bc}{an}$ days
5. *a* men can mow 1 acre in $\frac{bc}{a^2n}$ days
6. therefore *a* men can mow *b* acres in $\frac{b^2c}{a^2n}$ days

I don't really understand this solution. In statement 2, I assume it sets c=1. Then how come the amount of days become *bc*? Because if you go back to statement 1, setting c=1 results in *b* days only.

In statement 3, why is *n* in the denominator?

In statement 5, when the *a* acre is set to 1, why is there an additional *a* in the denominator?

Thanks.

Comment: If $10$ workers can finish in a day, then $1$ worker will finish in $10$ days. So if $c$ boys are needed for $b$ days, $1$ boy will have to work for $bc$ days.

Comment: Re going from statement-2 to statement-3, if $1$ boy can mow $a$ acres in $r$ days, then $n$ boys will take only $~\displaystyle \frac{1}{n}$th as long.  That is, $n$ boys work $n$ times faster than $1$ boy.  So, because you are changing the number of boys from $1$ boy to $n$ boys, you have to **divide** the time it will take by $n$.

Comment: In going from statement-4 to statement-5, the number of acres has been reduced from $a$ acres to $1$ acre.  This means that the number of acres has been **divided** by $a$.  Therefore, the corresponding **time** that will be required, for the **much smaller task** must also be divided by $a$.

Comment: "*Because if you go back to statement 1, setting c=1 results in b days only.*"  Yes, if you set c=1 for both the first two statements, then both indeed consistently tell you that $b$ days is needed. If you don't understand the above comments, google "inverse proportion" or take a look at [this example](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4204795/21813).